# WeChat share button

Tags: javascript, php, html, share, wechat

I am trying to find out if it is possible to create a share button on a website that shares to WeChat.

So just as you would with Twitter or Facebook to share a message or link back to the social network.

Has anyone managed to do this? Or has anyone confirmed that it is not possible?

thanks!

Comment: Shareaholic also has the WeChat share button. The solution is similar to AddThis. You can see a live demo of the WeChat share button in action [here](https://www.shareaholic.com/blog/introducing-the-wechat-social-media-buttons/) and also get the button code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They publish an APK for Android and iOS that allows you to do this from another native app.

As far as I'm aware, WeChat, like WhatsApp, does not support any web browser access so I don't think it's possible.

http://dev.wechat.com/wechatapi

Perhaps somewhere in the API you can create a share button on a website that opens the Android or iOS apps, but I don't think any WeChat access is possible from the desktop.

Comment: Yes this is what I found as well. Thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: To update anyone come around, about Whatspp, has been asked before and I personally tested to share from browser, work in Samsung S3 with Android 4.3, not sure if other version can work or not, worth to try. [Reference Question Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21451668/add-whatsapp-function-to-website-like-sms-tel)

Comment: The link in the above answer is no longer working.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the **[AddThis](https://www.addthis.com/)** service to embed a range of share buttons, including WeChat.

It doesn't seem to support opening the WeChat app with a pre-populated message (like when sharing to Twitter/Facebook) - probably because the WeChat app doesn't support this - but works around it in two ways:

- On Desktop: clicking the share button displays a QR code which the user can scan using their mobile device
- On Mobile: tapping the share button displays a share URL, a button to easily copy the URL, and another button to open the WeChat app. The user needs to still perform a couple of steps manually, but it's about the easiest it's gonna get.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The answer in this SO question should help you [WeChat sharing, how to change re-share description and thumbail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22636071/wechat-sharing-how-to-change-re-share-description-and-thumbail). It refers to a Javascript API WeixinJSBidge http://mp.weixin.qq.com/qa/index.php?qa=3163 with the documentation in Chinese but the code is still readable. Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thanks! I had seen that - but from what I can tell it checks to see if you are actually within the WeChat enabled browser? i.e. it doesn't really give share access to an external browser based website i.e. standalonewebsite.com in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to implement the integration of WeChat on Meteor before. The questions are:
1. Did you have the correct package ID and signature?
2. Did you get approved from WeChat and get the WeChat App ID?

I follow the tutorials and get my app work here: http://blog.sanuker.com/?p=691
Hope it helps! Good luck.